# How to make ChromeCast work with the sender application that runs behind the AWS ELB

Tags: chromecast

I am quite new to google ChromeCast, so please feel free to point out anything that just doesn't make sense.

Basically I am working on a sender application that ChromeCast can fetch videos from. For scaling reason, the sender application runs behind an AWS ELB. The problem is that the Chromecast client has to work with the same sender application once the video stream starts, but the AWS ELB randomly allocates requests from the chromecast to different sender applications.

Could someone advise a way to configure the AWS ELB to ensure one chromecast client always be allocated to the same sender application once the video stream starts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out myself. In this "AWS ELB <--> Sender Application Instances" 
structure, I managed to change the Sender application to store all the generated files in AWS Redis. Then, other sender application instances can also have access to those generated files, as the AWS REDIS is an unique instance accessible to all sender application instances.

All these changes are transparent to ChromeCast. Problem solved.